# Как получить последний символ из строки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная, которая содержит число. Хочу просклонять слово в зависимости от числа. Для этого мне нужно извлечь последнюю цифру и уже от нее писать условие

```js
number = 161;
last = number.substr(-1); //пробовал вот так
last = number.slice(-1); //и вот так
console.log(last); // но выдает ошибку
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Но не извлекается...

Comment: А если в кавычки 161 засунуть?

Comment: Это же число а не строка, преобразуйте в строку `number.toString().substr(-1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

number является числом, а вы применяете методы для строк и массивов.
Вам надо сделать

```js
var number = 161;
var last = number.toString().slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы не переводить типы туда обратно, используйте оператор взятия остатка от деления "%":

```js
var number = 161;
var last = number % 10;  
console.log(last);
```

Comment: Что значит %, а если число будет 164837362??

Comment: Я же написал, оператор взятия остатка от деления. Что будет? Проверьте

Answer (score 0):

Проще всю картинку разом показать:

```
function getNumEnding ( num, ends ) {
    if (
        num % 100 >= 11
        &&
        num % 100 <= 19
    ) {
        return ends [ 2 ];
    } else {
        switch ( num % 10 ) {
            case ( 1 ): return ends [ 0 ];
            case ( 2 ):
            case ( 3 ):
            case ( 4 ): return ends [ 1 ];
            default: return ends [ 2 ];
        }
    }
};
...
// варианты концовок
var ends = [ 'стрип', 'стрипа', 'стрипов' ];
// поисковая регулярка по несклонявшейся фразе типа " 21 стрипов"
var test = text.match ( / (\d+)[^\d]*(стрипов)/ );
// 1...21... стрип, 2-4...22-24... стрипа, 11-19...много стрипов
text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace ( test [ 2 ], getNumEnding ( test [ 1 ], ends ) );
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно и так сделать:

```
let number = 161
var last = String(number).at(-1)
```